# jQuery File Upload - make upload one by one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-file-upload

I'm using [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to make multiple uploads on my site. Whatever what I really like to do is upload one by one.

Ex:

I send 3 files [1,2,3].

The 1 file start the upload process while the others is paused.

When finish the upload will cal an AJAX to save the file on the DB.

When returns the success message from the file 1, the file 2 start to upload while the file 3 remains paused.

Is there a way to change the code so they do that?

Comment: I would make multiple forms and do something along the lines of `upload`--`[onSuccess]`->`upload`-`[onSuccess]`->... A wild guess, I don't know if this is reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:
open the file `jquery.fileupload.js`

In the options section, find these lines and set:

```
  options: { 
    .
    .
    .
    singleFileUploads: true,
    limitMultiFileUploads: 1,
    .
    .
    .
    sequentialUploads: true,
    limitConcurrentUploads: 1,
```